# How can you store leftover collar stays ("bones")?

Tags: clothing, storage, organization, laundry

Plastic "collar stays" are supposed to be removed from men's shirts when they are being washed and dried. I've been keeping mine in a small plastic bag on a closet shelf above my dress shirts.

[image: bag with collar stays]

The bag keeps them contained, and I can see them, and they are near my dress shirts, but as we lifehackers like to say, "There's gotta be a better way."  Any suggestions?

Comment: At first glance I thought that was a fridge... well, at least they won't go off so fast ;-))

Comment: If you wash the shirt in a lingerie bag, and put it on a hanger to air dry, will you really need to take out the stays?

Answer (score 3):

I used to keep them in an empty pill bottle.  Put a masking tape label on it, with "collar stays" or similar, and keep it in your sock drawer.  Then try to establish the habit of pulling out your stays when you take off a shirt, so they don't get lost in the laundry, and storing them in the bottle so you know where to find them when you put on a shirt that needs them.